# How to get SCSI properties from Storage Spaces pooled physical disks with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, storage, hyper-v, scsi

I am trying to extract the SCSI* properties for all the VHD files attached to my Hyper-V VM, using PowerShell.

This VM is configured with a Storage Space built upon 2 physical VHDs, in addition to the OS Disk.

Before configuring the Storage Space I was able to get the same with the following PowerShell command:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskDrive | select-object DeviceID,scsiport,scsibus,scsitargetid,scsilogicalunit | sort deviceid
```

After configuring Storage Space , I am unable to read the disk information, hence I'm unable to extract the information I need, like SCSIPortNumber, SCSIBusNumber, SCSITargetId and SCSILogicalUnit.

I tried with 3rd party tools, like [Visual SCSIExplorer](http://www.scsiexplorer.com), and I can see the SCSI information, so there should be a way to get the same.

Any Ideas?

Thanks.